# how to test model .h5

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to test model
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7NkK.jpg)

result:
TypeError:listdir: path should be string, bytes,os.PathLike, integer or None, not DirectoryIterator

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have imported images and labels once by the Image Data Generator and flow from directory in the fifth code block based on the image.

so for the model evaluation, you would just implement test_set in the `new_model.evaluate(test_set)` and not needed to implement flow from directory and with test_set variable, cause of this variable dedicated to (images, labels) that have been imported before, and strongly wrong.

so just change your code in the last block into `new_model.evaluate(test_set)`